# Can't access files I own

Tags: files, permissions, terminal, filesystems, access-control

I have created a folder /root/bin where I inteded to store my custom scripts. The idea is that these scripts shall be accessible to any user, so I added users to "users" group. I gave this group rwx permissions to the folder and all the files in the folder. I have set the owner of the group as well. However, I still may not access those scripts as any non-root users. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), the `/usr/local` directory and its subdirectories (e.g. the `bin` subdirectory) is for "local data, specific to this host", while `/root` is the home directory of the root user.

The home directory of root should normally be inaccessible by all ordinary users.

Administrators may, via the root account, install local scripts in `/usr/local/bin`, which would make them accessible to all users that has this directory in their `PATH` (or knows how to execute them given their absolute pathnames).

The scripts should not be writable by anyone other than the user who maintains them, which is likely to be the root user.  This mean that the ownership of these files should be `root`, and they should likely also belong to the `root` group, unless you have a special group for executables, such as `bin` or `wheel` (as found on some BSD systems; check you other executables under e.g. `/bin` and `/usr/bin`).  The permissions should be `r` and `x` for all, and possibly also `w` for the owner (unless the writable copy is kept elsewhere and the *installed* version is unwritable by all).

This means setting the permissions `755` or `555` on the files with `chmod`, depending on whether they should be writable by the owner (`755`) or not (`555`).

Answer (score -1):

```
FORMAT="ERROR: path: '%s' group name: '%s' group perm: '%s'\n"
find /root/bin -perm -g+rX -printf "%p %g %M\n" | \
    while read path group perm; do
        if ! [[ ${group} == "users" && ${perm:4:3} == "r-x" ]]; then
            printf "${FORMAT}" ${path} ${group} ${perm:4:3}
        fi
    done
ERROR: path: '/root/bin' group name: 'root' group perm: 'r-x'
ERROR: path: '/root/bin/script' group name: 'root' group perm: 'r-x'
```

What does it do? It lists all paths in `/root/bin` and checks if group is 'users' and permissing is 'r-x'.